# Creating an identifying variable and Cloning while modifying Variables

Tags: java, object, identifier

I have a class that creates Cars with a number of variables (year, brand, color, ... , sold (boolean), description (String), unique identifier (int) ).

In part of my project, I need to create a method to clone a Car, maintaining all variables except sold (reverts to SOLD_DEFAULT) description (reverts to DESC_DEFAULT) and unique identifier (generates a new identifier).

For now, my cloning code looks like this:

```
public Automobile cloner () {
        Automobile Clone = new Automobile(brand,year,color,a,k,p,DESC_DEFAULT,SOLD_DEFAULT);
        return Clone;     
    }
```

I have seen myself forced to include all the variables in () of the new instance or else I get an error: it sees no arguments.

My question is towards the identifying variable. It needs to be declared as an int that is private to my Automobile class, basically acting as a counter with the first car automatically having the identifying number = 1, second car = 2, etc... and if a car is cloned, identifying number goes up by one for the new instance. How would I go about doing that in my cloning method, and would I have to modify the way I clone the car ?

Also, let's say I have cars stocked in a table at slots 0 and 1, with slots 2, 3 empty, as in:

```
Automobile [] stock = new Automobile [4];
```

If I input these instructions:

```
Automobile aRandomCar;
  aRandomCar = stock[ 0 ];
  stock[ 3 ] = aRandomCar;
  stock[ 2 ] = stock[ 1 ].cloner();
```

and then I modify the year for stock[3] and the color for aRandomCar. Since it is an equality and not a new instance (like stock[2]), would this mean that my changing the year for stock[3] I also change it for aRandomCar and vice versa?

Thanks a lot !!!!

P.S.: Please refer to [Getters, Setters and Constructors in Java - Making a car and stocking it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985875/getters-setters-and-constructors-in-java-making-a-car-and-stocking-it) for further parts of code from my Class.

Answer (score 0):

Try to realize clone method from Object class and implement Cloneable interface. Use `super.clone()` to clone simple fields and manually clone composite fields.

Composite fields like your's classes not cloning itself. Only reference clones for you composite fields